# Is rails application slower if it has 'require ruby-debug' in config/environment.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does having 'require ruby-debug' in config/environment.rb slows down a rails application?

Answer (score 0):

It should include an extra overhead in the class hierarchy. You should only use it in development (and maybe test?) mode, not in production.